# how to reduce the waiting time for connection?

Tags: c, redis

simple script for connect server:

```
#include "hiredis.h"
int main(void) {
    int fd;

    unsigned int j;
    redisReply *reply;
    reply = redisConnect(&fd, "test.com", 6379);

    if (reply != NULL) {
        printf("Connection error: %s", reply->reply);
        exit(1);
    }

    reply = redisCommand(fd,"PING");
    printf("PONG: %s\n", reply->reply);
    freeReplyObject(reply);
}
```

if the server is available - everything is normal. If not - there is a long pause. How to reduce the waiting time to 2 seconds for example ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to modify the hiredis library, and the [anetTcpGenericConnect](http://github.com/antirez/hiredis/blob/master/anet.c#L128) function to make connect timeout aware. There's an example [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/trond/entry/socket_connection_timeout) of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know much about redis. but I assume, the redisConnect internally is basically also just calling connect() on an blocking fd.

so try setting the timeout beforehand using [setsockopt](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xns/setsockopt.html):

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
timeout.tv_sec = 2;
setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (void *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
```

this sets the send timout to 2 sec, for the receive, you basically do the same.

cheers,